# Combining Column result into Oracle?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g

I have below query

```
select distinct pj.pid,pj.seq, wm_concat(distinct pj.job)
from people_jobs pj
join entities aa on pj.pid=aa.pid and aa.mmd = 'A' and aa.mmd_cat in (50,70,80)
group by pj.pid, pj.seq
having wm_concat(distinct pj.job) like '%45%' and wm_concat(distinct pj.job) like '%70%'
```

Result

```
PID     SEQ  WM_concat(distinct pj.job)
9001800 10  16,45,70
9348300 1   16,45,70,90
9349100 1   16,19,45,54,56,70,81,82
9370600 1   19,45,55,70,90
9374000 1   10,42,45,70,90
9374000 3   10,45,70
9374400 1   45,70,90
9411100 1   45,54,57,58,70,90
9602500 10  19,45,70,90
```

Here I want combine seq by pid wise, pid should be distinctive, can you please help me?

Comment: What would  be desired result?

Comment: Desired result this way
PID     SEQ  WM_concat(distinct pj.job)
9001800 10  16,45,70
9348300 1   16,45,70,90
9349100 1   16,19,45,54,56,70,81,82
9370600 1   19,45,55,70,90
9374000 1,3   10,42,45,70,90
9374400 1   45,70,90
9411100 1   45,54,57,58,70,90
9602500 10  19,45,70,90

as you can see seq 1,3 combine on pid 9374000

Comment: Sorry, but this is unreadable. Post it as contents of the question, please.